# Xcode upload to app store fails CFBundleIdentifyer

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I'm trying to upload my app to the appstore and I'm getting the following error.

http://imgur.com/a/2ZjOU

I have the bundle identifier set as $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) and am still getting this.  I've also tried manually putting in the bundle identifier in case it couldn't figure out the variable.  Here's what my Info.plist looks like.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPFMx.jpg

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: You need to change `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)` with the identifier with which you have created your app in iTunesconnect. Like com.ios.mytestapp

Comment: It matches that perfectly right now :/